# Curve problem $x = x_0 + te^{x_0+1}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

I'm studying characteristic curves in PDE. In one of the problems I was doing, I came up with the following characteristic equation:
$$x = x_0 + te^{x_0+1}.$$
I need to isolate $x_0$ to proceed with the solution of the problem, because by the initial conditions the result is socked. Can you help me get around the problem?

Comment: Does EDP stand for PDE (Partial Differential Equations)?

Comment: Sorry for the error of the acronym. We work like this in Brazil. I ended up not translating...

Comment: If you really want to solve for $x_0$, you will need to use branches of the [Lambert W function(aka product logarithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), viz. $x_0=x-W(te^{x+1})$ ($t\neq 0$).

Comment: I think this will help resolve it. Thank you very much!